# Gridview check each row and update

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview ,gridview data is from database.I have a last column which is **asp:FileUpload** for user to insert new attachment if they want to,thing i wanted to do here is ,my backend c# will check if row asp file upload is not empty,then will upload new revision to that form.if empty,dont upload new revision to that form.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upload New Form" HeaderStyle-BackColor="DarkBlue" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" ItemStyle-Width="5%">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:FileUpload  ID="newdoc" runat="server"/>
       </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

[image]

this is the column i created for user to insert new file if they want.

```
protected void Button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
    string data = "";
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView3.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            FileUpload chkRow = (row.Cells[7].FindControl("newdoc") as FileUpload);
            if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
            {
                string id = row.Cells[2].Text + '-'+row.Cells[3].Text;
                data = data + id + ",";
            }
        }
    }
    string[] alldata = data.Split(',');
    foreach (string dataid in alldata )
    {
        if (dataid.Equals(""))
            continue;
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + dataid + "');", true);
    }
}
```

my c# logic is like this,i will check each row,if the uploadcontrol is not empty then dont add the id into data list,after collect all the row that needed to update new revision i will split the list update it 1 by 1,i try to alert out the id but value i get is empty.any ideas where i did wrong??
i suspeect something wrong in this line "                    string id = row.Cells[2].Text + '-' + row.Cells[3].Text;"

Answer (score 0):

use **BoundField** instead of **TemplateField**..

string test = row.Cells[2].Text;